# Module is not available, multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I spent 2 days already and didn't find the error:

> *Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not registered. The controller with the name 'clientController' is not
>   registered.*

I have 2 controllers and app.js:

```
js/app.js
js/controllers/client-controller.js 
js/controllers/login-client-controller.js
```

**ClientController:**

```
    angular.module('loginClientModule',[])
    .controller('clientController',
 ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state) {....//some code }])
```

**LoginController:**

```
    angular.module('loginClientModule',[])
    .controller('loginClientController', 
['$scope', '$http', '$state', function($scope, $http, $state) {....//some code }])
```

**The app.js:**

```
const app = angular.module('clientproviderApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'loginClientModule'
])
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/clients')
        $stateProvider
            .state('about', {
                url : '/about',
                template : '<h2>About stuff</h2>'
            })
           .state('loginClient', {
                url:'/loginClient',
                templateUrl:'views/login.html',
                controller: 'loginClientController'
            })
            .state('clients', {
                url: '/clients',
                templateUrl: 'views/clients.html',
                controller: 'clientController'
            })
    }])
```

**Index HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/client-controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/login-client-controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="clientproviderApp">
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am doing wrong? I tried several methods from stackoverflow and it didn't help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does `angular.module('loginClientModule',[])`do? What does `angular.module('loginClientModule')` do? Read the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem here is that `angular.module('myModuleName', [])` *creates a new module*. You are doing that in both `client-controller.js` and `login-client-controller.js`.

Instead, you should make sure that first, you create the module once using `angular.module('loginClientModule',[])` and then in the second file, just use `angular.module('loginClientModule')` to *get* the existing module.

Comment: Your last sentence is unnecessary: modules can be defined in whatever order.

Comment: Thank you!! I think that my problem was that i defined  the module being depended on (loginClientModule) after the app module was loaded. Thank you again!

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the correction, I removed that line.

Comment: @ProgIsMetal no. The problem is that you defined your module, added a controller to the module, then redefined the module again, and thus overwriting it completely, and thus losing the first controller. Read the answer.